# Functions continuous for a topology within a compactification

Tags: general-topology, continuity, definition

I wonder if the concept of the title, explained in more details thereafter, has a name.

For a topological space $X$, write $X'$ for its compactification (the kind of which is not relevant here).  Consider a continuous function $f\colon X' \to Y'$; is there a name for the following property?

> For any open $C$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(C) \cap X$ is an open of $X$

Answer (score 2):

First, a couple of observations:

(0) If $X$ is discrete then your property holds.

(1) If $Y$ is locally compact, then your property holds. For then $Y$ is open in $Y'$. So if $C$ is open in $Y$, then $C$ is also open in $Y'$, so $f^{-1}[C]$ is open in $X'$, and finally $f^{-1}[C]\cap X$ is open in $X$.

(2) If $X=Y$ and $f\restriction X=\text{id}_X$, then the property also holds.  Because then you must have $f[X'\setminus X]\subseteq Y'\setminus Y$ (prove as an exercise), and so $C=f^{-1}[C]\cap X$.

Now I would like to redo your property a bit. Say $P(X,Y)$ holds if for every two compactifications $X'$ and $Y'$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and every continuous surjection $f:X'\to Y'$, we have that $f^{-1}[C]\cap X$ is open in $X$ whenever $C$ is open in $Y$.

My question then would be:

> Is there a non-discrete space $X$ and a non-locally compact space $Y$ such that $P(X,Y)$ holds nontrivially (meaning $X$ and $Y$ are Tychonoff spaces and some $f$'s actually exist)?

By the way, I don't know if $P$ has been studied before. It may be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your great input!  I'm not sure it answers the question, though :-)  I'm working with spaces $X, Y$ such that $P(X, Y)$ doesn't hold, and I frankly have too little a background in topology to answer your question!  Why is it important for you that $f$ is a surjection, by the way?